# How to check if user already exists before regisration?

Tags: node.js, express

Hello i want to check out if user exist before registration, but of some reason
it does't works. something wrong is happening after else. Can some one tell me why? thank you.

```
//jj. using express
const app = express()
import express, { json } from 'express'

//jj. main array
const allUsers = [{name:"jane"},{name:"jacek"},{name:"morty"}];


//jj. main listener
app.post('/adduser', (req, res) => {
  let tocomapre = req.body.name 
  for (let user of allUsers ){
    if(user.name == tocomapre){
      console.log(user.name, req.body.name, tocomapre);
      console.log('user already exist');
      res.status(400).send("User alredy exist")
      break
    }
    else{
      try{
        const user = {name:req.body.name}
        console.log(req.body.name);
        allUsers.push(user)
        return res.status(200).send('user on board')
      }catch{
        res.status(500).send(" it's ain't good sthww")
      }
    }
  }
});

======================================================
//jj. request

POST http://localhost:3000/adduser
Content-Type: application/json

{
    "name":"morty"
}
```

Comment: Did you log what `req.body.name` is?  The code in your question does not show any middleware to read the body of the POST request and populate `req.body` so that may be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You have the `else` inside the `for` loop so that a new user is pushed to `allUsers` if it merely differs from the *first* existing user. This is wrong.

Replace the `break` with a `return` and put the `try-catch` block after the loop:

```js
let tocomapre = req.body.name 
for (let user of allUsers){
  if(user.name == tocomapre){
    ...
    return
  }
}
try{
  ...
}catch{
...
}
```

If the new user is found at any point during the `for` loop, you issue a 400 error and `return`. Otherwise you add the user.